# What is the equivalent of the factorial function, but for exponentiation?

Tags: reference-request, notation, terminology, exponentiation

The factorial function multiplies a given number by each number less than itself until reaching one. Does a function, notation, or literature yet exist regarding the idea of raising a given number to the power of each number one smaller until reaching one?
If I call this function f, f(4) would be $4^{3^{2^1}}$, f(5) would be $5^{4^{3^{2^1}}}$, and so on. I know that the factorial function has been generalized to decimals, but generalizing powers to decimals generally runs into all of the problems tetration usually faces.

I don't know if it's important to notice that the order of multiplication is irrelevant with the factorial function (i.e. multiplying by 1 at the end is the same as at the beginning) but would not be irrelevant here (1 to any power is 1).

Comment: See [A049384](http://oeis.org/A049384).

Comment: Such a function would be just an artificial curiosity, of no particular use.

Comment: Thank you @lulu as the OEIS link brought me to this Wolfram Mathworld page about this exact idea: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialFactorial.html

Comment: @quasi Curiosity is a virtue.

Comment: See [Exponential Factorial vs Tetration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1538895/13130) *AND* [Does domination of exponential-factorial by tetration generalize to higher-order hyperoperations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2178343/13130) *AND* [Can any number of factorials overtake the tetration function ${^x}10$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2176066/13130) *AND* [Tetrofactorial web page](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Tetrofactorial).

Comment: Thank you @JairTaylor

Comment: And thank you @DaveL.Renfro